# What does 同父异母或同母异父的兄弟 mean?

Tags: word

I think it means half-brother, but my book says it is step brother. I thought step brother is 继兄弟. What does 继 mean?

Comment: You are right. Your book is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

继兄弟 = **stepbrothers**.  Two unrelated people became brothers when their parents married each other

Stepbrothers are a result of a second marriage

同父异母兄弟 (同父兄弟/ 异母兄弟) = **half brothers**. When two brothers have the same father but different mothers (A man had a son with one woman and then had another son with a different woman.)

同母异父兄弟 (同母兄弟/ 异父兄弟) = **half brothers**. When two brothers have the same mother but different fathers (A woman had a son with one man and then had another son with a different man.)

Half brothers are mostly a result of a second marriage (but not always)

> *what does 继 mean?*

继 = 继任 - to succeed (a position)

继父, 继母 = stepfather, stepmother (继父 succeeds the previous father, 继母 succeeds the previous mother)

继兄弟 doesn't mean a brother succeeds a previous brother. It means the brother's relationship is through a 继父, 继母's marriage

Answer (score 0):

同父异母或同母异父的兄弟 = half-brother

> 同父异母 same father, different mother
>
> 或 or
>
> 同母异父 same mother, different father
>
> 的 [particle for attributives]
>
> 兄弟 brother

继兄弟 = stepbrother

> 继 step- (genetically unrelated family member because of marriage after divorce)